# Explode 1 column in dataframe that has a list of dictionaries, each dictionary should be a new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has a column that looks likes this:

| attachments.data | Heading 2 |
| --- | --- |
| [{'title': 'Test Title for Testing', 'unshimmed_url': 'https://www.etc.com'}] | 34 |
| [{'title': 'This is another Test Title for Testing', 'unshimmed_url': 'https://www.etc2.com'}] | 42 |

and would like to separate out `title` and make it a new column **name** and `unshimmed_url` to **link**

I've tried this but I think I'm missing a step because I lose the Heading 2 and Heading 3 columns and now its just the name and link columns..

```
s = df['attachments.data'].explode()
calcu = pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index=s.index)
df2 = calcu.rename(columns={'title': 'name', 'unshimmed_url': 'link'})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) the `attachments.data`, create the DataFrame in the same way, but then [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) back to `df`:

```
s = df.pop('attachments.data').explode()
df = df.join(
    pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index=s.index)
        .rename(columns={'title': 'name', 'unshimmed_url': 'link'})
)
```

`df`:

```
   Heading 2                                    name                  link
0         34                  Test Title for Testing   https://www.etc.com
1         42  This is another Test Title for Testing  https://www.etc2.com
```

---

Or without modifying `df` [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) and create a new DataFrame:

```
s = df['attachments.data'].explode()
df2 = df.drop(columns='attachments.data').join(
    pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index=s.index)
        .rename(columns={'title': 'name', 'unshimmed_url': 'link'})
)
```

Or with [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) `pd.Series` to build the new columns:

```
df2 = df.drop(columns='attachments.data').join(
    df['attachments.data'].explode()
        .apply(pd.Series)
        .rename(columns={'title': 'name', 'unshimmed_url': 'link'})
)
```

`df2`:

```
   Heading 2                                    name                  link
0         34                  Test Title for Testing   https://www.etc.com
1         42  This is another Test Title for Testing  https://www.etc2.com
```

---

DataFrame and imports:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'attachments.data': [
        [{'title': 'Test Title for Testing',
          'unshimmed_url': 'https://www.etc.com'}],
        [{'title': 'This is another Test Title for Testing',
          'unshimmed_url': 'https://www.etc2.com'}]],
    'Heading 2': [34, 42]
})
```

Comment: Thank you Henry, is there a way to keep it in the same position as the original column? When I use the first method you mention is places the new columns at the end

Comment: Not really. You can always reorder the columns manually or programmatically. But these are both new columns to the dataframe and for that reason they will be added to the end. If they are the first columns then you could concat `df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(…), df], axis=1)` instead but this just makes them the first 2 columns instead of the last 2.